# send variable with ajax call and get in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to sent a variable on an ajax call when I click on a button. The button has an id and on click of the button the id should pass through the ajax call to a php file

```
<button class="btn-view-products" id="mangoes">View Products</button>
```

and my js is

```
var gallery = $("#product-gallery"); 
var viewproducts = $('.btn-view-products');
viewproducts.click(function(){
pid = $(this).attr('id');
gallery.load("gallery.php?id="+ pid, hideLoading);
});
```

and in my php

```
$fname = $_GET["pid"];
$images_dir = "images/products/".$fname."/showcase/";
```

I am not getting the id value in php. 
please help.
thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: The URL is using id, while PHP is using pid. Might be a typo when posting here, so I wont offer it as an answer unless of course it is the problem.

Comment: Why don't put a link on your button and use PHP to create your link with pid?

Comment: $_GET["pid"] should be $_GET["id"] as you are passing "id" not "pid" ..? is that a typo..?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `id` from js and accessing `pid` in php. So replace your js to,

```
var gallery = $("#product-gallery"); 
var viewproducts = $('.btn-view-products');
viewproducts.click(function(){
  pid = $(this).attr('id');
  gallery.load("gallery.php?pid="+ pid, hideLoading);
});
```

Comment: Thanks David. I didnt notice it.

Comment: @Sergio What will be the problem, if changing in js? Is there any performance issue?

Comment: Not me downvoting btw

Answer (score 1):

In your JavaScript, you are sending a request to gallery.php?**id**= where in your PHP script, you are looking for $_GET['**pid**']. One of them needs to change as they don't match.

Change:

```
gallery.load("gallery.php?id="+ pid, hideLoading);
```

To:

```
gallery.load("gallery.php?pid="+ pid, hideLoading);
```

OR Change:

```
$fname = $_GET["pid"];
```

To:

```
$fname = $_GET["id"];
```